# What XML parsers can be used in Rhomobile?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, rhomobile, rhodes

I am able to establish an HTTP connection in a Rhodes application and now wonder how can I parse a XML. Which parsers are used to parse XML in Rhomobile? I searched the web but could not find a good tutorial for XML parsing. Please let me know if you find/found any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rexml or (if on a BlackBerry or slow device), RhoXML (which uses same syntax). Google Rexml for tutorials and code samples